# How do I get WiX to generate a 64-bit MSI?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, 64-bit, wix3.6

I am using WiX 3.6 and VS2010. I have a 32-bit installation working and I'm trying to get a 64-bit installation working.

- I set the Platform to "x64" in the Configuration Properties.
- I set the Platform attribute in the Package tag to "x64" in the install script.
- I changed the installation directory from "ProgramFilesFolder" to "ProgramFiles64Folder".
- I added the attribute Win64="yes" to each component.

I thought this was enough to generate a 64-bit MSI, but it still insists on installing everything in "Program Files (x86)" instead of "Program Files".

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you set the platform to `x64` on the Configuration Properties in the `wxs`?

Comment: @pupeno - In the `Package` element, set the `Platform` attribute to `x64`. i.e. `<Package ... Platform='x64' ...`

Comment: Isn't that the second item in your list of things? I've already done that, I was trying to figure out what the first item was, to see what I was missing.

Comment: @pupeno - You're right. Sorry, It's been a long time since I last worked on this stuff. I think that originally referred to setting the configuration properties in visual studio. At this point, the project I was working on has evolved to run `candle` & `light` directly to build an MSI. The build script passes a `-dPlatform=x64` parameter on the `candle` command line.

Answer (score 4):

My mistake. It was building the 64-bit version just fine, but I was testing an old x64 build which had not been correctly marked as x64. Once I had the x64 version building correctly, the resulting MSI was placed in bin/x64/Release but I was still testing the version in bin/Release. It pays to occasionally delete all your output files and rebuild.

Comment: Actually, your anwser isn't helpful, but the contents of your question is !