# Register .msi (setup project) for both x86 and x64 architectures

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project, regedit

I'm building a setup project for a biometric capture application.

The thing is, for it to work on the user's PC, i need to register the .exe path in Regedit.

I'm doing it already by targeting the "Program Files (x86)" folder, as you can see below, but in 32 bit PCs it does not exist, and thus, the application won't start.

[image]

What can I do to make it work for both 32 and 64 bit architectures?

Comment: Use %ProgramFiles% instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Still assuming installed there at all, using the MSI install directory is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSI installation does not require executable file registering.

It only can put information into the Windows Registry related to the [application removal, etc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/uninstall-registry-key).

By default MSI installer will put all files into the single root folder (for example, MS Office will be put into "C:\Program Files\Office" or to something like this). To configure target installation folder please use [TARGETDIR property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/targetdir).

TARGETDIR property is computed during the installation (moreover - it can be overridden by user). Default property "[ProgramFilesFolder]" is x86 location, however it exists everywhere. Property "[ProgramFiles64Folder]" is what you need, however it exists on the x64 OS only.

So, what's you need:

- Find action/step which will patch TARGETDIR
- Add action/step before to use "ProgramFiles64Folder" if it exists

Possible [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012385/how-do-i-make-a-64-bit-msi) can help you with examples.

After the steps above you application will select normal Program Files folder for x86/x64 operating systems.

Comment: Im slightly confused. Are you suggesting to use `ProgramFiles64Folder` to place a 32bit binary in 64bit Windows `Program Files` rather than `Program Files (x86)`? While it may technically work, that is very much against the OS conventions. Also I am certain a MSI can be made to set other registry keys, although I am not really familar with doing so.

Comment: So i do not need to add it's registry to the package? Is there something wrong with the project then, since you said it should be registering the key automatically.

Comment: @doutriforce, msi does not require any executable file registration. However you can do this to have access from Start Menu or to register your file for COM access. Nevertheless to have right directory - just use "ProgramFiles64Folder".

Comment: @ManushinIgor, i need to register it though. I'm consuming this application from a website and if i don't have it registered, the application won't start when i try to capture a fingerprint. I've used [TARGETDIR] and it worked fine.

Comment: @doutriforce, ok no problem. So we just need to configure TARGETDIR. As I said, the most of instructions are on the another SO question. I just re-wrote idea: we have to select TARGETDIR folder in depends of bits inside OS

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. Separate MSIs are required for separate architectures:
   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures/

so if you really need two different builds, one with your 64-bit code and another with your 32-bit code then you need separate MSI builds using the Visual Studio setup project settings. The 32-bit one main folder would be ProgramFilesFolder in the properties of the Application Folder directory, the 64-bit one will use ProgramFiles64Folder.

2. In both cases, the registry entry you need will be [TARGETDIR]Your.exe and this will just work, based on TARGETDIR being the name for the folder in both cases, and your executable not being in a sub folder.

Comment: I would have thought the Visual Studio setup project would be smart enough to know that if your project is x64 for TargetPlatform property, then the TARGETDIR should default to ProgramFiles64Folder.  After building a 64bit MSI and seeing my files go to Program Files (x86), that doesn't seem to be the case